# Current Transfor Ratio of an opto-coupler

Tags: opto-isolator

What does mean by the current transfer ratio of an opto-coupler for input side of the diode side of the opto-coupler and for the out put side of the transistor side of the opto-coupler.

Comment: When I search on Google for "current transfer ratio of an opto-coupler" the first link is this article: http://www.cel.com/pdf/appnotes/an3010.pdf  that explains it in detail. Why are you still asking here when it is so easy to find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Current transfer ratio is the ratio of receiver current produced divided by the emitter (photodiode) current. Typically 100% CTR means (for example) if the photo-emitter is driven with 1 mA then the photo-transistor (or photo-device) will draw 1 mA from the supply. Of course there are prescribed conditions for the receiver circuitry by which this is measured and other circuits used in the receiver side may not achieve that level of CTR.